How to avoid this android kivy app crash (matplotlib)
new to forum so please don’t mind errors on my side.
I’m working on a simple kivy app which creates databases and outputs data from in png.
It’s about football club; players in a team, their attendance to training sessions and output of attendance for particular month.
So I’m using matplotlib for png output file, and I’ve made an android package with Colaboratory, installed the app to my phone. The app is working in VSC, and is also working on phone to the point when I try to create a png file by pressing the button, then it crashes - it exits app window, without outputting anything.
I think it’s due to this part of code and matplotlib:
# Set autowidth columns
the_table.auto_set_column_width(col=list(range(2, len(df_result.columns))))

plt.title(f'Popis dolazaka - {app.category_chosen} - {target_month}.{target_year}', fontsize=12, loc='left')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig(f"Popis_dolazaka_{app.category_chosen}_{target_month}_{target_year}.png", bbox_inches='tight')

The whole code is here, but I don't think that there are errors elsewhere, because the app crashes when I press the button to get output.
Is there something particular I should insert in buildozer spec or any known problems with outputing png/pdf to android with python?
Any help would be much appreciated.
The code is working in VSC, I get a png output and all is well. On the android phone I get a crash.
Here is the full code - https://github.com/jfort0/football_app

Do you have a stacktrace? Also, what happens if you wrap the logic you feel is the one causing the crash, with a try/except block?

For the stacktrace see: How to debug a Kivy/Kivymd app for android?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
